# Show only notes in org-mode without org-mode-related info?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How can I get just the notes from org-mode heading without any "technical" stuff? 
I mean, I want something like that

```
* Some project
  - some note 1
  - some note 2
** some chapter
   - another note
   - noooote
** TODO some big todo
   - something to note for the task
   - another thing
** some chapter
```

instead of that

```
* Some project
  - some note 1
  - some note 2
** some chapter
   - another note
   - noooote
** TODO some big todo
   CLOSED: [2011-11-10 Thu 19:51]
    - State "DONE"       from "STARTED"    [2011-11-10 Thu 19:51]
    CLOCK: [2011-11-10 Thu 19:33]--[2011-11-10 Thu 19:51] =>  0:18
    CLOCK: [2011-11-04 Fri 15:29]--[2011-11-04 Fri 15:29] =>  0:00
    :PROPERTIES:
    :Effort:   0:30
    :END:
   [2011-11-04 Fri 15:29]

   - something to note for the task
   - another thing
** some chapter
```

EDIT: I figured out I can accomplish that using exports (with `#+OPTIONS:   <:nil d:nil`), but its not really convenient - I mean, I need to press `Ctrl-c Ctrl-e u`, then switch to new buffer `Ctrl-b temp-buffer`, then delete everything from it `Ctrl-x h` `Ctrl-w`, then add my export `Ctrl-y Meta-y`. Thats a LOT of keys to press.

Besides that, I couldn't get rid of stuff like `- State "DONE"       from "STARTED"    [2011-11-10 Thu 19:51]` because formally it is just a note - exactly the thing I "wanted" to keep.

Comment: You can use org publish with the export function `org-publish-org-to-org` which generates cleaner org-mode files from your source files. Check http://orgmode.org/manual/Publishing-action.html#Publishing-action

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although you'll need to manually repair much of your existing org-document, the solution would be to use Logbook drawers.

To file your todo-state changes into a drawer (default to LOGBOOK) you can use (see [Tracking TODO state changes](http://orgmode.org/manual/Tracking-TODO-state-changes.html#Tracking-TODO-state-changes)): `(setq org-log-into-drawer t)` or `:LOG_INTO_DRAWER: t` as a property on the headline.

You can also use `(setq org-clock-into-drawer t)` to place all your `CLOCK:` lines into the `:LOGBOOK:` as well.  If you want your clocking to go in a separate value, replace `t` with the string you want as your drawer title (e.g. `(setq org-clock-int-drawer "CLOCK")`

Then when you export your `#+OPTIONS: d:nil` will prevent any of those drawers from being exported, so none of that information will appear.